# How can I prevent fancybox from closing? Want to make the user click the Close button instead of anywhere on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello StackOverflowers!

My site that I am finishing up is having a few problems, the contact form is in a fancybox and whenever you click the form it closes, which is obviously something I don't want as I want the form to be usable in the fancybox?

The link to my site is: http://raychampionfitness.com

I have used other examples found on stackoverflow that claim they work, but they are now working at all?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This needs to be set to false instead of true:

```
/* Using custom settings */
$("a#inline").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});
```

Also, you are loading jQuery twice on that page - once by wordpress automatically and it looks like you might have added the other in the theme or something.

Comment: Thank you very much Karl! Fixed it and spotted something I didn't see! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is using the new v2 of fancybox you now have to set:

```
modal: true
```